# Firefox WebDriver randomly not actually executing clicks

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Our Selenium tests were developed in C# and were running just fine for months but recently we noticed that a number of tests started failing when executed with Firefox WebDriver.

After investigating the test results and executing tests locally we noticed that from time to time clicks on random elements are executed (we can tell because the visual state of the button or the link changes to what looks like a clicked element)

Browser console does not indicated any errors. WebDriver logs show that click was executed.

Will be grateful for any help.

**Edit:**

- Version of Selenium WebDriver - 2.53.0
- Versions of Firefox - (tried few) 33.0.1, 43.0.1, 45.0, 46.0.1
- Firefox scale 100%
- tried with native events on and off
- tried with additional implicit waiting before click

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very specific, so I'll try to offer possible ways you can choose to resolving it.

You didn't indicate which driver and browser versions you used. If you didn't observe failures for months ant suddenly they appeared, my first guess would be that FF version you use on test machine(s) got updated (or driver version in tests was changed), and new combination can work differently. I had situation like this when tests behavior changed, updating driver version helped.

Another option would be to try and see which webelements get misclicked more often than others and insert instructions that check if they are displayed before executing actual click.

Also, try to do step-by-step debugging (if you haven't already) and see if you observe wrong clicks then

Answer (score 0):

One thing we've seen in our testing is that if we're clicking around on the VM while a Selenium test is running on our VM, it can actually prevent clicks from going off.

But another thing we've encountered is that the clicks are often not working where they should be, so you can counter this by using JavaScript clicks instead of Selenium.

For elements that fail regularly, switch the element.Click() to a method utilizing the code below:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ElementToClick)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that click does not work even when clicking manually so we'll be investigating in that direction.